# Какой из перегруженных методов будет вызван если в параметр передаётся null?

Tags: c#

Какой из перегруженных методов `foo` будет вызван из `bar` и почему?

```C#
static void foo(byte? arg) { }
static void foo(short? arg) { }
static void foo(int? arg) { }
static void foo(float? arg) { }
static void foo(double? arg) { }
static void foo(ValueType arg) { }
static void foo(object arg) { }

static void bar()
{
   foo(null);
}
```

Comment: Я попробовал, вызывается `byte?`, в каком бы порядке описания не стояли. Почему - надо дальше копать.

Comment: Почему `byte` из числовых типов понятно по этому ответу https://stackoverflow.com/a/719566/8324991 А вот что насчёт `object` и `ValueType` нужно дальше копать.

Comment: порядок описания вроде как не влияет, только возможность конвертирования - и тут `byte?` ближайший получается (более специфичный / узкий)

Comment: Вообще лепить такие перегрузки, которые сходу непонятно как вызываются - плохая практика. И даже если такое где-то встретилось, от такого кода надо избавляться. Другими словами, в нормальном мире знания приоритета вызова перегрузки при неоднозначном вызове окажутся бесполезными. Ещё важен контекст реализации. Обычно такие перегрузки для оптимизаций делают, чтобы было меньше ветвлений внутри метода из-за абстракций, при этом результат достигается всеми перегрузками одинаковый. И снова - без разницы, получается, какая перегрузка отработает.

Comment: [Спецификация языка](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/). Раздел _12.6.4 Overload resolution_, подразделы _12.6.4.5 Better conversion from expression_ и _12.6.4.7 Better conversion target_.